# Analog to Digital Converter and Negative Voltages

Tags: microcontroller, avr, adc

I'm using the ADC on an ATtiny24 to record a AC signal. The ADC has a range from 0-3.3V. I'm using a precision rectifier to get rid of the negative portion of the signal. I've attached a picture of the circuit I'm using for the rectifier. I'm using an LMC6484 as the op-amp with 3.3V to the V+ rail and 0 to the V- rail. I'm using 1N4004's as the diodes and 10k for the resistors.

My logger is able to graph the waveform of the rectifier very well. BUT the oscope shows that the output of the rectifier  varies from -0.5 to 1V. But my micro shows a signal with the same waveform that goes from 0-1.5V! If I replace the precision rectifier with a simple diode/resistor combination, I get a waveform that varies from -0.X volts to Y volts (depending on the input through the function generator). The micro follows the shape of the waveform correctly but the voltage range is from 0.X to Y volts.

I always have a little bit of a negative signal even with the precision rectifier and when I graph the results through my logger, it appears that the largest negative value has been moved up to zero, so I seem to get a larger range than the input.

Is this a result of putting in negative voltages into my ADC? Does it take the negative voltages, set that as 'ground' with respect to other voltages?

I've input positive voltages into the logger through a power supply, and it reads those voltages perfectly! It follows the shape of the waveforms very well too. The only problem seems to be the range. I'm completely lost.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The small negative voltage is probably from a diode drop.  No, the A/D isn't going to convert negative values and then make the most negative the zero reference somehow, although a external circuit could do that.  Show a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Op-Amp_Precision_Rectifier_%28Improved%29.svg

Comment: That is the circuit I'm using. It doesn't seem to matter WHAT circuit I use: a simple diode and resistor circuit results in the same problem. The shape of the waveform is very good but the output from the rectifier circuit seems to be moved up somehow. I wish I could attach pictures, I have one from an oscope and a graph from the resulting log. :(

Comment: Any chance you have the settings wrong on your oscope?

Comment: Make a real schematic, showing actual component values.  And a photograph of your circuit.

Comment: How is your scope ground connected to the circuit?

Comment: My scope, battery for the micro, and function generator are all grounded together.

Comment: Is the signal AC coupled?  The op-amp's input impedance will change as it goes in and out of common-mode.

Comment: @markrages: Honestly, I'm not completely sure. I've been debugging this problem all night and can't remember. I have all the grounds connected properly, the DC reading for the micro work. I thought it was a grounding issue initially but that proved wrong. Then I thought I was doing something wrong with the rectifier and replaced it with a diode/resistor. If I input 2VPP sin wave through a function generator, the resulting graph of the data will be a wave from 0-2V. The shape of the wave looks correct but the peak voltages seem skewed.

Answer (score 7):

Your scope is set to AC coupling.

[image]

Comment: +1 Sure. This must be it. Looks like I didn't read the question :). // @Nevermored, if the V- supply pin of your opamp is at the same voltage than its non-inverting input, you don't need the diodes. Just let the opamp clip the output. Even without diodes, the opamp is not able to produce negative voltages. So, it will still give you the positive portion of the signal. There is a speed penalty, but at 50 Hz, you won't notice anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

Last data for AC signal:

- [0 to 50] Hz.
- [-22 to +22] V.

If the AC signal can go down to 0 Hz, and you need to capture it, but with no special reason to rectify it in an analog way, you can do something like this:

[image: Schematic]

This way, you don't need diodes, or opamps. If you really need to rectify it, you can do it in the digital domain (by firmware).

The equation \$V_x=f(V_{in},R_1,R_2,R_3)\;\$ is:

\$V_x=\dfrac{R_3(3.3R_1+R_2V_{in})}{R_2R_3+R_1(R_2+R_3)}\$

Known data: \$V_{inMin}=-22\;V\$, \$V_{inMax}=22\;V\$, \$V_{xMin}=0\;V\$ and \$V_{xMax}=3.3\;V\$.
Equations: two.
Unknowns: \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$.

You may freely choose one of the three unkowns, and the other two will be set by your known data and the two equations.

So, for instance, if you freely choose \$R_1\$, you may end up with:

R1= 3.3 k\$\Omega\$
R2= 495 \$\Omega\$
R3= 582 \$\Omega\$

With this, a [-22 to +22 V] Vin range will be mapped into a [0 to +3.3 V] Vx range.

Comment: I don't actually need all of the signal. I just need to see what kind of voltages the signal is producing. I don't know what I'm lowest frequency is since it is variable. It will go anywhere from 0-50Hz. Why do you suggest I not rectify the signal?

Comment: Well, if it can go down to 0 Hz, you cannot use a cap. I'll correct the circuit.

Comment: Also, I don't know the max and min voltages of the AC signal. It is a variable, probably asymmetrical signal.

Comment: Seems I was writing my answer when you were editing yours, and our schematics were the same. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @stevenvh Sorry.

Comment: @Telaclavo - No pasa nada :-)

Comment: @Nevermored You should find out the range for the AC signal, to have a better answer. If its range is larger than [-3.3 to +3.3 V], you need third resistor (not to exceed 3.3 V at Vx).

Comment: @stevenvh Very good :). Wow, I should learn Dutch right away.

Comment: Don't! I hear it's terribly difficult. (Though for some reason it seems easy to me ;-))

Comment: @Nevermored Wait. If Vin can go up to 22 V, you do need the third resistor. I'll add it. Please let me know also what is the minimum voltage that Vin can take.

Comment: Can you explain how you found the resistors values? They don't seem to come automagically out of the equation.

Comment: @stevenvh That is just maths. This site is about electronics. I assume he knows how to solve a system of equations. And, if not, he didn't ask about that, anyway. He wanted to know how to do what he wants.

Comment: @Nevermored I suggested you not to rectify the signal *in the analog domain* (you can still do it in the digital domain) because you didn't say why you need that, and that makes me think that you actually don't need it. Rectifying it will involve opamps and diodes, and bypass caps for the opamp, and more wiring.

Comment: Ah. Okay that makes sense. Believe me, the ONLY reason I'm resistant to the idea is because the circuit is already built and integrated with the rest of the system. 12 hours ago, I would have jumped on this. Removing it will be a significant pain. I'm not trying to be a jerk.

Comment: From his first comment I have the idea that he can do with the peak value, so he can write a software peak detector too. I agree to do it in software if you can save components that way.

Comment: I need to map voltages to other signals in the system. So I'm not just interested in the peak value of my signal.

Comment: @Nevermored - But you said you don't need all of the signal. What do you need then? A few samples, subsampling? An average value, RMS? What are those voltages you want to map?

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this! I ended up using this and it definitely made my circuit much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate and scale with just three resistors. For a situation where maximum input > \$V_+\$ and minimum input < \$V_-\$ I found a dead easy way to calculate the scaling resistors.

Use a pull-up to \$+3.3V\$ and and a pull-down to \$GND\$. Then we have

[image]

(the +5V should be read as +3.3V)
We'll consider two situations: one with \$V_{IN}\$ = \$-22V\$ and one with \$V_{IN}\$ = \$+22V\$.
We'll have a set of two equations, so we can choose 1 resistor value. Let's take \$10k\$ for \$R2\$.

First. \$V_{IN}\$ = \$-22V\$. The ADC should then be at \$0V\$. That means that there won't be any current through \$R3\$, since there's no voltage difference. Then \$R2\$ and \$R1\$ form a voltage divider with

\$ \dfrac{0V - (-22V)}{R2} = \dfrac{3.3V - 0V}{R1} \$

or

\$ R1 = \dfrac{3.3V}{22V} \cdot  10k\Omega = 1500\Omega \$

Found our first value.

Then the second situation. \$V_{IN}\$ = \$+22V\$. The ADC should then be at \$+3.3V\$. That means there won't be any current through \$R1\$, since there's no voltage difference. Then \$R2\$ and \$R3\$ form a voltage divider with

\$ \dfrac{22V - 3.3V}{R2} = \dfrac{3.3V - 0V}{R3} \$

or

\$ R3 = \dfrac{3.3V}{18.7V} \cdot 10k\Omega = 1765\Omega \$

Found our second value. So

\$R1\$ = 1500\$\Omega\$,
\$R2\$ = 10k\$\Omega\$,
\$R3\$ = 1765\$\Omega\$.

Comment: Nice schematic picture ;-)

Comment: @Olin - Yeah, I've got this artist who makes them for me :-).