# Interfacing a phone's microphone to a MCU

Tags: audio

I am doing some speech recognition, and my phone is my microphone. I have used it to collect data for PC and would like to do the same on my Tiva C launchpad. I planned on using an app,such as this [one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=multimediasol.app.microphone), to send data from a phone's microphone to an audio jack, in real time.

I am wondering how to connect the phone and the MCU. With a 3.5mm jack and an aux cable? Stripping the wires and plugging them in ADC input pins? (L or R ?)
Is it possible to get the same data on PC and MCU with the same speech signal?

EDIT: I should mention that the sound produced using this app is as good as the recorded one.

SOLVED. Look in the comments.

Comment: Have a look here: [How to give analog input from 3.5 mm jack to FPGA (Spartan 3e)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206986/how-to-give-analog-input-from-3-5-mm-jack-to-fpga-spartan-3e) - you'll need to do pretty much the same. Use the tip and ring of a 3.5mm jack plug (I suspect your phone only has one mic so it will output the same on L and R channels of the jack).

Comment: @Finbarr Okay, I now understand why it's not possible the way I thought it's gonna be. Can you recommend me a rectifier circuit then? Or a board 'component' that has a mic + everything else?

Comment: You don't need the rectifier - that answer was about measuring the peak level. Just follow the circuit diagram shown there and you should be fine.

Comment: @Finbarr Thanks for replying. I will do that. One more thing. What's the performance of using a 3.5mm jack vs directly plugging the wires in the breadboard?

Comment: No performance difference in this situation, using a plug and socket just makes it easier to remove the cable. Plus you can use a standard 3.5 to 3.5 jack cable without cutting it up.

Comment: @Finbarr Are you sure this circuit will be okay for speech recognition? Guy in that other thread said sound would lose too much information using this.

Comment: Digitised voice over ISDN runs at 8k samples per second, which should be more than adequate for recognition and easily achievable with a fairly basic micro. Whether it has the processing power to run the recognition software is another matter.

Comment: @Finbarr It's a single word recognizer, so I hope it will. What I meant to ask is, will this circuit with a capacitor and two resistors distort the signal?

Comment: No. The resistors are there to bias the ADC input to the midpoint of the converter range (I don't know this particular board but it's likely to be 3.3V, 5V or a separate analogue reference - you'll need to check). The capacitor blocks the DC bias voltage from getting to the phone output. The components will actually form a high pass filter with a cutoff of around 30Hz, which is no bad thing.